# How to change the text inside the return button from keyboard in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, keyboard

Is it possible to change the text in return key to "Hide"?

[image: Here attached the keyboard image for your reference, change the return key text to "Hide", Is it possible.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't change it to arbitrary text, only to a set of predefined options. You need to set the `returnKeyType` property of your text field to one of [these options](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfp/UITextInputTraits/returnKeyType).

```
typedef enum {
    UIReturnKeyDefault,
    UIReturnKeyGo,
    UIReturnKeyGoogle,
    UIReturnKeyJoin,
    UIReturnKeyNext,
    UIReturnKeyRoute,
    UIReturnKeySearch,
    UIReturnKeySend,
    UIReturnKeyYahoo,
    UIReturnKeyDone,
    UIReturnKeyEmergencyCall,
} UIReturnKeyType;
```